# Force ghc to import a hidden module

Tags: haskell, ghc

I needed some functions out of a hidden module. If I `import Graphics.UI.Gtk.Types` I recieve:

```
Could not find module `Graphics.UI.Gtk.Types'
it is a hidden module in the package `gtk-0.12.4'
```

How can I import this hidden module without editing and recompiling gtk?

Comment: Ok, so if gtk is in your project's dependencies and this still happens then something else is weird with your environment.       ... You don't have your project online, have you? Just to make sure there's really not something else wrong with the cabal setup.

Comment: @leftaroundabout he's asking about hidden modules, not hidden packages.

Comment: Indeed. Sorry, I got it completely wrong...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can not expose modules that are not exported by a package.  If you need something from that module to use the package then the functionality should be available via another (exposed) module.

Comment: 'If you need something from that module to use the package then the functionality should be available via another (exposed) module.' Not always.

Comment: This typically occurs when the need to create orphan instances arises and the maintainer doesn't want new dependencies added to their package.